# Solidity Contract bytecode contains many 'f'

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

my contract bytecode which is generated by go-ethereum abigen has something like

```
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....
```

what does it means??

Comment: You can use a smart contract disassembler to figure out what those sections are. Without having the smart contract source code and compiling it ourselves, we cannot tell.

Answer (score 1):

All of those `FF...` sequences are the same length - 40 hex characters, which is 20 bytes:

```
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
^                                      ^
+-------------- 20 bytes --------------+
```

What else is 20 bytes? Ethereum addresses. (Background: [How are ethereum addresses generated?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3542/how-are-ethereum-addresses-generated))

What these sequences of bytes represent are *bitmasks* which are used to extract 20-byte addresses from the 32-byte storage slots used by the EVM.

See my answer to this previous question to understand more: [Why in some contracts I see: If (condition_1 & 0xfffffffffffffff...)?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97232/why-in-some-contracts-i-see-if-condition-1-0xfffffffffffffff)